# ISO Country Code for lon/lat 0.5degx0.5deg cells

Tags: geospatial

I have a dataset of Koppen climate classifications for the global land mass on a 0.5degx0.5deg lon/lat grid (simple table giving lon, lat and Koppen class for each of approx 85,000 cells as it has changed in decadal steps since 1900 provided by http://hanschen.org/koppen). I want to be able to map this across countries and need a similar dataset that identifies the ISO country code for each grid cell (but current state is sufficient, don't need history).

Comment: http://api.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=10.05&lng=20.05&username=demo ?

Comment: That site provides a limited number of codes where lat/lon coordinates are input.  I have 85,000 data points.

Comment: You could use https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7a8585998b7f470b85235dcdb560c7e2 and compute them yourself, but realize not every grid cell is in a single country: some are in multiple countries and others are in international waters.